# How to resolve ReferenceError: server is not defined

Tags: node.js

I tried to create server in Node.js using VSCode editor and I'm getting this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: server is not defined
    at <anonymous> (undefined:8:1)
    at Module._compile (undefined:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (undefined:1213:10)
    at Module.load (undefined:1037:32)
    at Module._load (undefined:878:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (undefined:82:12)
    at <anonymous> (undefined:23:47)
```

Here is my code

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    console.log(req);
});

server.listen(3000);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you haven't defined the variable here. Two possible ways to create the server.

```
http.createServer((req,res)=>{
   console.log(req);
}).listen(3000);

// or

const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
                 console.log(req);
               });
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: See also [w3schools: Node.js http.createServer() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_http_createserver.asp)